# Alternative to Rasterio Mask module for clipping a raster using masked geojson

Tags: rasterio, python-3, extract-by-mask, code-review

I am clipping a raster (.tif file) using a mask vector (.geojson) file.

```
with rasterio.open(url) as src: 
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
```

But, this rasterio.mask module is taking some time to create this NumPy array out_image.

I want to create the clipped image as fast as possible.

Is there any alternative way (for eg. from rasterio.io import MemoryFile module) to clip a raster with a mask vector layer using Rasterio (only using Rasterio and not using any other libraries) ?